# How should one approach a coworker's wardrobe malfunction?

Tags: colleagues

While on a video call with a group of coworkers, the coworker whose laptop was being used to call me in leant over her laptop to use it for something, and due to her (somewhat) low-cut top and the height of the laptop, I was able to see right down her top.

Nobody else was able to see as I was the only one on the call, and I didn't react outwardly at all.

I decided to not bring it up at all.  Other options I considered were to wait 5 minutes (by which time she'd likely not have anyone able to easily see her screen) then message her "hey, sorry this is awkward - you may want to not lean over your laptop so much in that outfit."

I'm not sure if I made the right decision.  On the one hand, if she doesn't know, then she's not possibly embarrassed by it.  If she does, then she's not possibly embarrassed by me seeing, because she doesn't know I did.  On the other hand, if she doesn't know, then it can happen again.

Was I correct?  (Also, should this be here or in interpersonal?)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere OP was the only one dialed in remotely, everyone else was together in a meeting room.

Comment: Why would you need to mention it at all? Exercise a little decorum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How to approach this?

Simple answer: you don't.

You will either come across as a creep (and possibly face HR) or you will embarrass her making a very awkward workplace dynamic.  It's a lose-lose scenario.

If it becomes a repeated thing thats a different issue.

If its a one-off just ignore it.